# Injecting custom callback in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, callback

I have a custom module which sets up a hash to be stored in my sql. As part of this it rolls a its own _changed accessor.

```
module MyAwesomeCustomModule
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
      after_save: wipe_preferences_changed
   end

   module ClassMethods
      def blah
      end
      etc
   end
end
```

and then in my model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   include MyAwesomeCustomModule

   after_save :something_that_expects_preferences_changed_to_be_available

   blah
end
```

unfortunately, the `after_save` defined in the custom module runs before the one defined in the model. Is there a way to get the array of all callbacks and append to it? Is there a way to write a custom `after_after_save` callback? Is there a way to specify priority/ordering of `after_save` callbacks?

What would be a good way to resolve this race condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spite of the order of model callbacks, the current design makes the module and the class very coupled.

To solve the current problem as well as improve design, you can define an expected callback in the module's method, and then the class who includes this module is free to respond it or not.

```
module MyAwesomeCustomModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_save: wipe_preferences_changed
  end

  def wipe_preferences_changed
    # previous logic to wipe
    process_further if respond_to :process_further
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyAwesomeCustomModule

  # Feel free to write this or not
  # The content is the previous 
  # :something_that_expects_preferences_changed_to_be_available
  def process_further
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your original strategy (2 after_save callbacks) all you should need to do is move the `include` statement below the model after_save.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base    
   after_save :something_that_expects_preferences_changed_to_be_available
   include MyAwesomeCustomModule

   blah
end
```

Callbacks are executed in the order they are defined. The include statement acts (very roughly) like you had copy and pasted the code from the module at that point, so by putting the include statement above the after_save in your model you were causing that callback to execute first.